# Error en linea del if de php

Tags: php, vscode

[image: Me pueden ayudar por favor diciendo porque me aparece en el codigo subrrayada la linea 1 de este codigo? osea la del if]

tengo un problema, me subrraya la linea de este código y dice qué hay un error de sintáxis, la cuál no encuentro el problema, soy nuevo en esto y tengo aun mucho por aprender, aagradezco de su apoyo, saludos.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. El código siempre va como texto con formato de código en lugar de imágenes, eso ayuda a que podamos reutilizar el código en lugar de reescribirlo y permite que más usuarios deseen ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Quizá el `<?php` del principio...

Comment: ya se solicionó, no pusé en la línea anterior un ;
Gracias @DavidJP